# Xcode Scrollview scrolling vertical not working when content to scrollview is added

Tags: ios, xcode, scrollview

when I run my App without content in the scrollview I can scroll to all 4 possible directions.
As long as I have Content added to the Scrollview (I want to display a very big Image (500x500)) it is not longer able to scroll to the left or right, just top and bottom are possible (tested with labels etc too, not working).
How can I make my Scrollview scroll to the the left and right with content in it?

my code for that:

```
[scrollermap setScrollEnabled:YES];

    [scrollermap setContentSize:CGSizeMake(500, 500)];
```

edit:
it seems that the scrolling to the left and right isnt working when there is content in the scrollview, what is pretty strange.

Thanks, Maurice A.

Comment: please help, i dont know what to do

Comment: How are you adding the image in the scrollView?

Comment: I did it with the Interface builder, cause it is more clear for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the contentSize of the scrollview.

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(500,500)];
```